# トレイリングスラッシュ（URL末尾の/）の無い場合の404について

Tags: apache

以下の状況になっており、サーバ側の設定によるものかと思うのですが、
原因が特定できません。何かアドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。

本番環境
https://example.com/test　のリンク
→https://example.com/test/　に遷移

ローカル
https://example.com/test　のリンク
→404エラー（URLをコピーするとhttp://example.com/test/）

Comment: `.htaccess` やApacheの設定ファイル (`httpd.conf`) などを確認する必要があるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

コメントにあるように`.htaccess`やApacheの`conf`フォルダにある設定ファイルに `DirectorySlash Off` が含まれていないか確認してみてください。

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash